# Find all $p\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $p\circ q=q\circ p$ for all $q\in\mathbb{R}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

a) Find all polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(q(x)) = q(p(x))$ for every polynomial $q(x)$.

b) Find all polynomials $p(x), q(x)$ such that $p(q(x)) = q(p(x))$.

Thanks

Comment: Yes,I have.I have made as far as the answers were given.But wasnt able to proof if more than the solutions i have provided exist!

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Consider what happens if $q(x)$ is a constant polynomial, say $q(x)=a$: $$p(a)=p\big(q(x)\big)=q\big(p(x)\big)=a\;.$$

But there’s a constant polynomial for every $a\in\Bbb R$, so ... ?

Comment: Yes i got the constant part.But how do we prove if there is a polynomial of some degree greater than 1? How do i see upto what degree it can go, inturn analyze for more solutions.

Comment: @Sai: What I did in the hint tells you exactly what polynomial $p(x)$ **has** to be, because it tells you the value of $p(x)$ at every real number.

Comment: Oh! Thanks sir.I missed that part.My bad

Comment: @Sai: You’re welcome.